# Venn Diagram of drawing an Ace and then a King

Tags: probability

I know that this is the solution and I understand it in terms of the products of the probability and also as a tree.

[image: example]

However, what is the geometric (venn diagram) representation of Pr(A and B)?

Comment: Two intersecting circles?

Comment: how would they be intersecting? to me, they are mutually exclusive! :(

Comment: @user56833 A is the chance that you draw an Ace, B the chance you draw a King, since you understand that the chance of drawing both in the order Ace then King, it is easily seen that it would be two intersecting circles, and where they overlap it is equal to Pr$(A\cap B)$.

Comment: @TheCodingWombat but the overlap would imply that within event B contains ACE outcomes.... event A should only have ACE outcomes and event B should only have KING outcomes.

Comment: @user56833 The A event is outcomes where the first draw is an Ace and the second can be whatever. B is where the first can be whatever and the second is King. So the overlapping part is where the first is Ace and the second is King.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this website](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-draw-a-Venn-Diagram-to-the-probability-of-two-independent-events) may give you a hint.

However, obviously posting a link-only answer is not enough, so here's what I have drawn based on the answer on that link:

[image]

In the diagram above:

- $A$ represents the possibility of having picked an Ace first and King second.
- $B$ represents the possibility of having picked an Ace first, but **not** the King on the second pick.
- $C$ represents the possibility of **not** having picked an Ace first, but having drawn the King on the second pick.
- $D$ represents the possibility of **not** having picked an Ace first and **not** having picked a King second either.
- $A+B$ represents the possibility of having picked an Ace first.
- $A+C$ represents the possibility of having picked a King second.